# How to know whether it is HTTP-POST or HTTP-GET in Generic Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

Here is the code, I am having:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;


public class HelloServlet extends GenericServlet {

     @Override
     public void service (ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          out.println("Hello World");
          out.close();

     }

}
```

I do NOT want to use HTTPServlet. I want to use GenericServlet but want to find out whether it is HTTP-GET or HTTP-POST in Service method. Can you provide me sample code ?

Comment: But the HTTP methods are specifically for... well, HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the first parameter to [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) (if possible) and then call its [getMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod%28%29) method.

Since you said you don't want to use `HttpServlet`, this is perhaps not an option for you either. In this case, you could try to hunt down the source code of the `getMethod()` method above and do whatever it does in your own code.

Comment: Can we use CGI environment variable (REQUEST_METHOD ) in GenericServlet ? How to call an CGI environment variable ?

Comment: You should really use `HttpServlet` -- CGI presupposes HTTP, too, so in the end, you'll have to do your own HTTP parsing (which you don't want) or give in and use the appropriate classes for the job.